# Return one result for each search value

Tags: sql

How can I return a unique value based on a set of non unique values being searched?

For example:

If I wanted to return one phone number for a list of 4 people who can have more than one phone number - but I can only use one phone number for each person. It doesn't matter which phone number I use to reach them because any number that belongs to them will get me to them.

I don't think something like this exists - but if I could use something like the DISTINCT modifier except it would be called FIRST - it would solve my problem:

```
SELECT FIRST ID
FROM Sample_Table
WHERE ID in ("Bob", "Sam", "Kyle", "Jordan")
```

In picture - from this

[image: Sample_Table]

I'd like that (or any) query to return

[image: something like this].

I'm using this type of query in a db where for 200 "ID"s there are millions of "Unique Values", so it is hard to get crafty.

*EDIT* The Unique value in my db has numbers and letters in each value

Comment: Please edit your tags with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "first id" in a SQL table.  Tables represent *unordered* sets.  You can accomplish what you want (if I understand correctly) using aggregation:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(UniqueValue)
FROM Sample_Table
WHERE ID in ('Bob', 'Sam', 'Kyle', 'Jordan')
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Would this change if the "Unique Value" column has numbers AND letters for each value? This query is still yielding about 1.4M results for 98 "ID" values

Comment: @PJT . . . This query cannot return more than 98 id values if that is the number of *distinct* ids in the table.  That is what `GROUP BY` does, one row per value.

Answer (score 0):

using group by and max method can help you:

```
 select id
,uniquvalue
    ,max (typeofvalue)
    from Sample_Table
    group by
    id
    ,uniquvalue
```